# Can't add google tag in React project

Tags: html, reactjs, google-analytics

I can't add my google tag to the bottom of the  as described by google.
I've tried several different ways, and as for now my code looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
        var script = '<div> \n\
        <script type="text/javascript"> \n\
        /* <![CDATA[ */ \n\
        var google_conversion_id = xxxxxx; \n\
        var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params; \n\
        var google_remarketing_only = true; \n\
        /* ]]> */ \n\
        </script> \n\
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js"> \n\
        </script> \n\
        <noscript> \n\
        <div style="display:inline;"> \n\
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" src="//googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/viewthroughconversion/xxxxxxx/?guid=ON&amp;script=0"/> \n\
        </div> \n\
        </noscript> \n\
        </div> \n\ ' ;

        window.eval(script);

        document.body.innerHTML += script;
}
```

I'm getting different errors in the Google Tag Assistant:
First of all, the one single tag/script adds 4 Remarketing Tags, which I don't really understand why:

[image]

Second I'm getting errors - the blue one says "Code should be placed directly above the closing  tag." So apparently my code don't put the code where it belongs. This might be the first problem."

The red errors says: "No HTTP response detected" and "Tag is included in an external script file".

How can I get rid of these? The "No HTTP response detected" is pretty crucial as I can understand. But I can't really figure out a good way to "inject" the script to the body of my html in React.

Please let me know if you have the golden answer :-)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason of not putting directly into HTML file?

Comment: It’s a single page application, and I need to put it on several different pages :) also it’s react, and not plain html :)

Answer (score 0):

For the way you are doing I will suggest use something of

```
this.gtmScript = document.createElement("script")
this.gtmScript.src = "Link or gtm"
this.gtmScript.async = true
document.body.appendChild(this.gtmScript)
```

Do this in `componentDidMount` and check if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, what is gtm?

Comment: Ah, Google Tag Manager I assume?